# Getting the range of a numeric stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a `DoubleStream s`, I can do `s.min()` or `s.max()` but not both, as any one of them will consume the stream.

Now suppose I have

```
class Range /* can add code here */ {
    private final double min;
    private final double max;
    Range(double min, double max){
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
    // can add code here
}
```

How can I get the range of the stream? (Other than by `s.collect(Collectors.toList()); new Range(s.stream().min(),s.stream().max());`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call [`DoubleStream`'s `summaryStatistics` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#summaryStatistics--).  It returns a `DoubleSummaryStatistics` object that contains a min and a max, plus a few other statistics: average, count, and sum.

`IntStream` and `LongStream` have similar `summaryStatistics` methods.